# How can I get the list if all items persisting in my dynamoTable?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How can I get the list if all items persisting in my dynamoTable? All the examples I have seen there I have to pass hash key values. I want some operation for select * from X table;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) operation to retrieve all data in your DynamoDB table. More information [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html) as well.